# Caesar cipher: How to encrypt a character that deletes information?

Tags: encryption

I have a question that is asking for encrypt a message, using a modified version of a Caesar Cipher. The catch being that I am expected to use all 256 characters of the extended ASCII library. This part is reasonably straightforward.

However, when I was running the encryption, the length of the message changed. After tracking down the issue, it seems that if a particular shift is used, some of the characters are converted to ASCII 127, which is the character for "delete". As such, it deletes the previous character, instead of appending a character to the message.

Any suggestions on how to get around this, while maintaining the integrity of the cipher?

If it helps, I can write the solution in either Python and VBA.

Comment: Keep the whole thing in bytes, from the plaintext to the ciphertext, then do an encoding at the end - hex/b64

Comment: Be warned that there is no singular thing that is defined as "extended ASCII". There are schemes like Windows-1252 that at least define all codes, but that's about it.

Comment: You can of course easily make an extended ASCII *alphabet* that excludes all control characters, and 0x7F etc, and perform the shift using that alphabet....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a cryptography question but let me answer anyway.

I think you are mixing up different layers of your application. If you get an ASCII character that deletes other characters, or more likely one of the many non-printable characters - you can still keep that code point in your encrypted string. It just isn't a good idea to try and print that encrypted string after decoding as ASCII in a terminal. Just use a hex representation and you should be fine.

Comment: That is an interesting approach. I hadn't thought about doing it that way. Might see if I can code it.

Comment: I'd keep the binary / bytes and only use hexadecimal representation of those bytes when trying to print them out.